# executePackage seems to take a long time to launch subpackage

Tags: performance, ssis

I am a relative beginner at SSIS so I may be doing something silly.

I have a process that involves looping over a heterogenous queue and processing the objects 1 at a time. The process is currently being done in 'set logic' and its dropping stuff. I was asked to rework it in a looping manner, so that decision has been made for me.

I have chosen to implement queue logic in 1 package and the actual processing in another package.

This is all going relatively well considering...

I now have the process up and running, but its slow. 9 seconds per item. Clearly I cant present this solution. :-)

One thing i notice, 1.5 - 2 seconds of each loop are on the ExecutePackage Task in the queue loop.

I cant figure out how to get a hard number, I am using the flashing green box method of performance tuning. The other steps seem to be very fast. Adding indexes, changing sql to sps, all the usual tricks have helped.

1. Is the UI realiable at all with regards to boxes turning white/yellow/green?  Some tasks report times in the progress tab, some dont seem to. So I am counting yellow time.
2. Should calling a subpackage be that expensive? 1 change i made was I change 'RunInASeparateProcess' to FALSE. I did that because the subpackage produces the following message otherwise:

   Error: 0xC0012024 at Script Task: The task "Script Task" cannot run on this edition of     Integration Services. It requires a higher level edition.
   Task failed: Script Task
3. The reading i have done seems to advocate multiple packages.  Anyone have any counter patterns? Should i stay the course? I started changing to 1 package.  Copy/paste doesnt seem to work well w/ SequenceContainers. I would also need to recreate all the variables in the parent package. Doable, but im not sure that is the answer.
4. Does anyone know of any tuning resources/websites/books they would be willing to share.

Update - I have been tearing things down in an effort to figure out what the problem is. I was thinking it was the package configurations passing variable values. I dont think that is it. I can pass variables to another package w/ nothing in it and it is fast.

I can make the trivial subpackage slow by adding the two connection managers to it. 
I suddenly realize I may be making and breaking a connection to both an Oracle Server and a SQL server in both the main package and then the sub package.

Am I correct in this observation?

Is there any way I can reuse the connection between the two packages? 
     When i google it, most of what i see is suggestions for passing the connection string.

UPDATE - I combined the two packages into one. This performance is not about 1.25 seconds per item, down from about 9. the only thing i can point to that changed is i am now reusing a single connection instead of making multiple connections.

Thanks, I appreciate any help you are kind enough to offer.

Greg

Comment: Are you basing your performance on how it behaves when run in BIDS? What version are you using (I ask because you mention compiling and there is no real compile in SSIS but 2012 is closer than other versions)?  You may be seeing additional overhead since you are running in BIDS.  Try enabling logging and run from the test server as a scheduled job and see how the performance is.

Comment: Sometimes the UI is not reliable (2008 version). especially, when you have packages inside another package. It's also slower than running the package on the server with a SQL job. Try running the package with a SQL job on the server and analyse the speed from there.

Comment: William, I used the term compiling incorrectly. We have BIDS 2005. I will try getting the package on the server. There are change control procedures to deal with, so i am trying to get as far as i can before i go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you enable logging, I'd suggest running the package from a command window using `dtexec`. While that doesn't perfectly duplicate the server environment, it does have the advantages of (a) eliminating BIDS as a potential performance issue and (b) being something you can do without jumping through change control hoops.

Comment: I will look into this today. I have made a single monolithic package  ( sigh ) and it is running fast enough to catch up from beginning of our data in a day or so. 
I am looking at a couple other issues , hoping to get 1.3 seconds down to ~.5 and then i will look at dtexec and configurations in prep for the big day. 
thanks for answering